# Iphone - Custom cell - can't set UILabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I try to set my value in custom cell in a UITableView. But when I lauching it, there are no error but my value is not setted in the UILabel!

and idea?

Custom cell:

```
@interface InscriptionCustomCell : UITableViewCell {

IBOutlet UILabel *titreCell;
IBOutlet UITextField *contenuCell;
```

}

View with my UITableView:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InscriptionCustomCell";

InscriptionCustomCell *cell = (InscriptionCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InscriptionCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (InscriptionCustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    [cell.titreCell setText:[model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contenuCell setPlaceholder:[model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}else {
    [cell.titreCell setText:[model.listModuleInfoSupp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contenuCell setPlaceholder:[model.listModuleInfoSupp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Make sure the labels are connected in your nib to appropriate outlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like  pratikshabhisikar said, connect the labels in the nib to the outlets in your class.

Then use UILabel.text property to set label text.

```
cell.yourCustomLabel.text = @"text";
```

or

```
NSString * labelText = [something...];
cell.yourCustomLabel.text = labelText;
```

Also please use the standard Apple terminology for your tags when you create questions. For example: ios,uikit etc.

Comment: I've made a post on my blog about using custom cells, maybe it will be useful to you http://effectivemobility.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-custom-cells-in-your-uitableview.html